# Use Dependency Property to pass a callback method

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, calendar, attached-properties

I am using the [Jarloo's calendar control](http://www.jarloo.com/wpf-calendar-control/) in order to display a calendar in my WPF software. For my needs, I added that each day contains a list of items, lets say `List<Item> Items`.

The Jarloo calendar is a second project within my main visual studio solution. I am using this control this way :

```
<Jarloo:Calendar DayChangedCallback="{Binding DayChangedEventHandler}"/>
```

As you can see, I wish I could pass a method from my main project to the calendar's project so that I can, within the Calendar's constructor, add the method as a eventhandler of the DayChanged event.

However, the item received through the dependency is null...

In the calendar code, my dependency property is defined as :

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DayChangedCallbackProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DayChangedCallback", typeof(EventHandler<DayChangedEventArgs>), typeof(Calendar));
```

My "DayChangedEventHandler" is defined as

```
public EventHandler<DayChangedEventArgs> DayChangedHandler { get; set; }
void DayChanged(object o, DayChangedEventArgs e)
{
}

// i set this way the DayChangedHandler property so that I can bind on it from the view
DayChangedHandler = new EventHandler<DayChangedEventArgs>(DayChanged);
```

Does someone has a hint for me?

Thanks a lot :) .x

Comment: Have you set a DataContext somewhere? Otherwise the binding has no source object.

Comment: @Clemens The datacontext has been set and works on other piece of xaml bindings such as `<TextBlock FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="10" Text="{Binding Quantity}"/>`

Comment: The property is set *after* the constructor has executed. You need to register a PropertyChangedCallback with the property metadata in your dependency property declaration (the 4th parameter to Register).

Comment: @Clemens Thanks! I've defined a method with attach my handler to the DayChanged event but while registering the PropertyChangedCallback it says: `A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Jarloo.Calendar.Calendar.AttachCallback(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)`... And I cannot says that all my calendar class is static :/

Comment: The PropertyChangedCallback must be a static method. It gets the current instance that the property is set on by the first parameter. You would cast it from DependencyObject to Calendar.

Comment: @Clemens Sure i got that but if I do `static PropertyChangedCallback pccb = new PropertyChangedCallback(AttachCallback);`, then my "AttachCallback" method has to be static, then my event DayChanged has to be static and finally I'm stuck with the property' getter and setter methods which cannot be static because of the "GetValue"/"SetValue" which ask: `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.DependencyObject.GetValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty)'`...

Comment: AttachCallback has to be static (that's why I wrote **static method**), but not the rest. Cast the DependencyObject parameter to your Calendar instance. See the example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: @Clemens yeah I saw that ! thanks :)
Still my dependency property has a null value, but i'll look into it before asking for further help !

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example regarding your non-static field issue:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   public bool IsChecked
   {
       get { return (bool)GetValue(IsCheckedProperty); }
       set { SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value); }
   }

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IsChecked.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
   public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("IsChecked", typeof(bool), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(PropertyChanged)));


   private static void PropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       MainWindow localWindow = (MainWindow)obj;
       Console.WriteLine(localWindow.TestString);
    }

   public string TestString { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
       InitializeComponent();

       TestString = "test";
       this.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

And here is the XAML to test it:

```
<CheckBox Content="Case Sensitive" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
```

When the property is changed, the callback is called and in thix example, you can access the non static TestString property.

Comment: Mmhh thanks ... seems that i'm tired, cant' wait for weekend...
However, the value of the property is still null ... the binding is working, is `DayChangedEventHandler = new EventHandler<DayChangedEventArgs>(DayChanged);` the right way to do to set my handler (which is furthermore called through the dependency)?

Comment: @dotixx can you try to follow that exact syntax? new PropertyChangedCallback(PropertyChanged), and your handler definition should be private static void PropertyChanged... i tried this yesterday and worked as expected.