# How to bind in custom control

Tags: wpf

In my WPF application, I made my own control and want to bind to a property in it. This is what I tried so far:

```
public partial class BreadcrumbContainer : Grid
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TestProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Test), typeof(string), typeof(BreadcrumbContainer), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public string Test
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TestProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TestProperty, value); Refresh(); }
    }

    public BreadcrumbContainer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Refresh()
    {
        // never gets called
    }
}
```

And I try to bind to my `Test` property like this:

```
<controls:BreadcrumbContainer Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Test="{Binding SearchMessage}"/>
```

And in my view model, I have a property `SearchMessage`. All my other bindings are working, so it must be something I'm doing wrong in my `BreadcrumbContainer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from Adam Nathan's WPF Unleashed

> .NET property wrappers are bypassed at runtime when setting
>   dependency properties in XAML. Although the XAML compiler depends on
>   the property wrapper at compile time, WPF calls the underlying
>   GetValue and SetValue methods directly at runtime!

The property wrapper in your case is your `Test` property. So basically, don't put any logic in there since it never gets called in runtime. The proper way to do this is to use a property changed callback. One example for you is in the answer [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30939209/use-dependency-property-to-pass-a-callback-method). Notice the callback initialization in the `DependencyProperty.Register` call.

There is also the "official" documentation in [Checklist for Defining a Dependency Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/custom-dependency-properties#checklist-for-defining-a-dependency-property)
 - *Implementing the "Wrapper"*:

> In all but exceptional circumstances, your wrapper implementations should perform only the GetValue and SetValue actions, respectively. The reason for this is discussed in the topic [XAML Loading and Dependency Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-loading-and-dependency-properties).

From [XAML Loading and Dependency Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-loading-and-dependency-properties):

> Because the current WPF implementation of the XAML processor behavior for property setting bypasses the wrappers entirely, you should not put any additional logic into the set definitions of the wrapper for your custom dependency property. If you put such logic in the set definition, then the logic will not be executed when the property is set in XAML rather than in code.

This is one example of a baffling behavior in WPF that will drive you mad if you don't know. It's not really your fault but I suggest reading WPF Unleashed by Adam Nathan - and all the online documentation - to learn more about these types of pitfalls.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But having a `PropertyChanged` callback to call my `Refresh()` won't work because it needs to be static and I need to add to the `Children` property

Comment: @Darius - although the handler is static, its first argument is the instance of your custom control (cast to it from DependencyObject).